# Accessing a Map via index?

Tags: java

Is it tossibe to aceess a `Map<Integer, Integer>` via index?

I need to get the second element of the map.

Comment: no. its order depends on what you put in the map. so the second element might not be the second you entered

Comment: What is the `second` element`? The one with key `2`? The second you `put` into the `Map`?

Comment: No you can't non of map implementation is index based

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the wrong data structure. If you need to lookup by key, you use a `Map`. If you need to lookup by index or insertion order, use something that lets you index, like an array or list or linked list.

If you need to lookup by both, then you need to create a composite data structure that tracks both keys and insertion order (implementation would be backed by a `Map` and one of the above aforementioned data structures).

There's even one built into the framework: [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: The first sentence of this is a bold one, given that we don't know the nature of the OP's problem.

Comment: +1 Another solution might be TreeMap in which case the second will be the second smallest, possibly the second largest.

Comment: @arshajii: We know that he's trying to use a data structure for something it isn't conceptually equipped to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to access a map "via index", but it looks like you want a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which provides a predictable iteration order:

> ... which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map *(insertion-order)*. Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key `k` is reinserted into a map `m` if `m.put(k, v)` is invoked when `m.containsKey(k)` would return `true` immediately prior to the invocation.)

Answer (score 0):

Map does not store elements in the insertion order. It stores elements into buckets based on the value of the **hashCode** of the element that is being stored. So no, you cannot get it by index.

Anyways, you could imitate something like this by using the **LinkedHashMap** implementation of the `Map` interface, which remembers the insertion order (unlinke the **HashMap**).

You would have to "hack" with manual index counter and the code would look something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map= new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("1", "one");
map.put("2", "two");
map.put("3", "three");
int index= 0;

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    if (index++ == 1) {
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
"two"
```

Which is what  you want.

Answer (score 0):

A definition of index is not applicable to `Map`, as it's not an ordered collection by default.

You can use a `TreeMap`, which implements `NavigableMap`, and then iterate the key set using the `navigableKeySet()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get the second element all the time. Why not use a iterator and then do next ,next.

Answer (score 0):

It will depends of Map implementation, but if you want to retrieve the second inserted element, you can use a LinkedHashMap and then create an iterator on values.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();

map.put(1, 1);
map.put(2, 2);

Integer value = null;
if (map.size() > 1) {
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = map.values().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        value = iterator.next();
    }
}

// value contains second element
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap from apache commons-collection. It implements Map and provides some methods from the List interface, like get(int index) and remove(int index).

It uses an ArrayList internally, so performance will be better than iterating on a Map to retrieve a value at specified position.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any "cleaner", but:
If use LinkedHashMap and u want to retrieve element inserted second following will work

```
List keys = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
Object obj = map.get(keys.get(1));
    //do you staff here
```